# NSMergeConflict with multiple threads

Tags: ios, core-data

```
A 1 <----> * B
```

I'm using core data in an iOS application.  A and B are entities that have a 1-to-many relationship between A and B.  I have a background thread that updates and creates B. A is updated on the main thread, except when I add B to A on the background thread, because of the inverse relationship A gets updated. I have separate MOCs for the main and background thread.

I've added a `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on the main thread, but I get a `NSMergeConflict` on the background thread for A. Looking at the `userInfo` of the `NSMergeConflict` doesn't help, because all the attributes are the same, it's the to many relationships that I imagine are conflicting, and those arent returned by nsmergeconflict.

I've tried adding a `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` to the background thread, but it now deadlocks when both threads try to save.

I've looked over the answer for this [`NSMergeConflict` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405912/iphone-coredata-error-nsmergeconflict-for-nsmanagedobject).  I've tried adding the 
`mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` notification, but I'm still seeing the NSMergeConflict. I don't think that any of the `NSMergePolicy` options are applicable, because I want to keep all of the persistent store's changes except for the relationship.  I'm also not clear on how I can "manually resolve any conflicts".

How would I be able to resolve or avoid these conflicts?

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166815/core-data-on-multiple-threads

Comment: For now, I've re-architected so that all my writes occur in the same block.  Not ideal, but it works for now.  I may write up an example and use one of my support requests to apple for their input on what is the correct way of handling it.